# The meaning of " had money on the event"

Tags: meaning

> That Monday was one of the hardest days in the memory of the White Hussars. They were thrown against a skeleton-enemy, and pushed forward, and withdrawn, and dismounted, and ‘scientifically handled’ in every possible fashion over dusty country, till they sweated profusely. Their only amusement came late in the day when they fell upon the battery of Horse Artillery and chased it for two miles. **This was a personal question, and most of the troopers had money on the event;** the Gunners saying openly that they had the legs of the White Hussars. They were wrong. A march-past concluded the campaign, and when the Regiment got back to their Lines the men were coated with dirt from spur to chin-strap.

This is from "The Rout of the White Hussars " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-rout-of-the-white-hussars.htm

I don't understand the meaning of

> This was a personal question, and most of the troopers had money on the event;

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 7):

"had money on the event" means that the soldiers had bet on the outcome of this particular skirmish. It seems that there was some outstanding grudge or ill-feeling between the   Horse Artillery and the White Hussars, that is the sense in which it was a personal question".

It is well to recall that most of Kipling's writing is now over 100 years old, and sometems he used dialectical forms, so he is not always a safe model to imitate, although he was in my view an excellent writer.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It is very helpful for me.

Comment: To 'have money on' something is by no means obsolete. Although I find some of Kipling's writing very moving, especially his poetry, there is much that is racist. There is a glaring anti-Semitic slur in the work being discussed.

Comment: @Michael No, "To have money on something" is not at all obsolete, but other phrases and idioms that occur in Kipling's works are.  He is not a safe model for a learner who does not grasp how language has changed since his day. As a Jew myself, I did not fail to notice the antisemitic phrase in the story. Nor have I failed to notice other racial inequalities in his work. But then racist attitudes pervaded the worlds he wrote of. But nor have I failed to notice the anti-racist text of, say "The Mother Lodge".I choose to take Kipling as I find him, in context. Others do not. Still no safe model.

Comment: I would add that moving as much of his verse is (I am particularly fond of "The Old Issue"and "The Sons of Martha" ) I find his later stores more so, particularly such Post WWI work as "The Madonna of the Trenches", "The Wish House" and "The Janites". There are generally many fewer racial issues in those works., too.

Comment: I have to say that I agree with everything you say. I cannot read 'Merrow Down' aloud without faltering. I am a convinced anti-imperialist yet I am moved by 'Recessional', and I have been known to say that something obsolete or bygone is 'one with Nineveh and Tyre', which can earn quizzical looks. I have similarly mixed feelings about HG Wells.

Comment: I'm not sure about this instance, but "had money on" might not mean that they literally bet. Often people say "I bet that X will happen" as a figurative way of saying they expect it.